# select into and overwrite

Tags: sql-server, select-into

I have this SQL Server Agent, that creates a backup table, doing this:

```
DECLARE @date datetime, @insert_cmd varchar(1000)
SET @date =GETDATE()
set @insert_cmd = 'select * into [tablename_'+CONVERT(varchar(100), @date, 112 )+'] from tableA'
exec (@insert_cmd)
```

Trouble is, select * into table only works if table doesn't exist already.  Is there a way to change this to insert into tablename_.... without caring, and just overwrite if necessary?

I've tried looking at using sql to check if the table exists, doing something like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tablename', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP tablename;
```

The trouble with that is how to do i situate those quotes so they work to build the date/time added to the table name?  I've tried a few variations, but none have panned out:

```
/* errors with quotations: */
set @del_cmd = 'IF OBJECT_ID ('[tablename_'+CONVERT(varchar(100), @date, 112 )+']', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP [tablename_'+CONVERT(varchar(100), @date, 112 )+']';
```

Comment: There is no such syntax. Why can't you say `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX); IF OBJECT_ID('tablename_' + CONVERT ...) IS NOT NULL BEGIN SET @sql = N'DROP TABLE tablename_' + CONVERT ...; EXEC sp_executesql @sql; END`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, perfect, how can i mark this as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: You can self-answer with the code that solved the issue. I'll up-vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full credit to @aaronBertrand, Here's the code i ended up with:

```
DECLARE @insert_cmd varchar(MAX), @del_cmd NVARCHAR(MAX), @date datetime
SET @date =GETDATE()
  IF OBJECT_ID('tablename_' + CONVERT(varchar(100), @date, 112 ) ) IS NOT NULL 
   BEGIN 
SET @del_cmd = N'DROP TABLE tablename_' + CONVERT(varchar(100), @date, 112 ); 
EXEC sp_executesql @del_cmd; 
   END
SET @insert_cmd = 'select * into tablename_'+CONVERT(varchar(100), @date, 112 )+'] from TableA'
EXEC (@insert_cmd)
```

Big thank you!